# JSONPath filter by node key not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xpath, jsonpath

I'm trying to select nodes containing a certain key using https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath (a Node.js implementation of Stefan Goessner's [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)), but only if the node's path matches a certain parent and grandparent.  I'm able to filter by the **grandparent**, but not the parent.

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "a": {
        "x": {
            "d": 4,
            "e": 5
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "y": {
            "d": 40,
            "e": 50
        }
    },
    "c": {
        "z": {
            "d": 400,
            "e": 500
        }
    }
}
```

And this extraction query which looks for nodes having grandparent `a or b` and key `d`:

```
$..[a,b][?(@.d)]
```

I get this result which is correct:

```
[
    {
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5
    },
    {
        "d": 40,
        "e": 50
    }
]
```

But for the life of me, I CAN'T select by the parent `x` or `y` portion.

Given the paths to every node, a regular expression might look something like `.*\.(a|b)\.(x|y)$`

If I can't get this to work, then I have to retrieve all matching nodes and then filter the list by each node's path ending in `.x` or `.y` which could be a lot of wasted cycles for large data.  Here are the online tools I've been using:

http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

http://jsonpath.com/

http://jsonpathfinder.com/

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it, I was able to get the query working in 5 minutes with [JSPath](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspath) (you can select it in from the [jsonquerytool](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/) popup or visit http://www.jsonquerytool.com/#/JSPath):

```
..a.x.{.d}
```

and

```
..b.y.{.d}
```

Results respectively:

```
[
    {
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5
    }
]
```

and

```
[
    {
        "d": 40,
        "e": 50
    }
]
```

I feel like I've found a use case that JSONPath just can't tackle, but since it was the first thing I tried, I don't have the highest confidence in its query syntax.

Unfortunately JSPath has a known bug/feature since 2013 where it returns a reference to a node but not its path, unlike JSONPath which provides a `jp.nodes()` method which returns a `{path: ..., value: ...}` object containing the path that matched the pattern and the value of the node there.  This makes JSPath relatively useless for any real-world navigation within a large JSON tree (like the kind produced by parsers like [Babylon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babylon)).

Hopefully knowing where these frameworks fall down will help someone save time deciding which to use.  I get the feeling that currently there may be no JSON query language that satisfies the 2 relatively modest needs of 1) matching path/value simultaneously and 2) getting the path to those matches.  Unfortunately GraphQL uses web server endpoints instead of raw data so it operates at a layer 1 step too high.  Maybe there is an opportunity here for someone to provide a GraphQL-like framework but for JSON, that also returns the path(s) to results.